# Too Many Rows throwing but only one is selected

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, ora-01422

I have this procedure which just deletes a row based on a column field called `AppID`. This procedure get's a value from another column called `AppNbr` based on that rows `AppID` column. The procedure is failing with a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception when it tries to `SELECT` a row. This is the PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    lvnApplNbr NUMBER;

    PROCEDURE deleteAppl(applId IN VARCHAR2) IS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN
            SELECT ApplNbr -- Exception thrown here
            INTO lvnApplNbr
            FROM Appl
            WHERE ApplID = applId;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        END;
        -- ... Delete it after some logic
    END; -- End Procedure
BEGIN
    ...
    deleteAppl('571E00BA-70E6-4523-BEAC-4568C3DD1A7D');
    ...
END;
```

The `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception is thrown when it `SELECT INTO`s. I have no idea why it is throwing that error because if I just query this:

```
SELECT ApplNbr FROM Appl WHERE ApplId = '571E00BA-70E6-4523-BEAC-4568C3DD1A7D';
```

Only one row will come back with the correct `ApplId`.

What is going on?

Comment: Is `Appl.ApplID` a primary key or has a unique constraint? Otherwise the error makes total sense.

Comment: @TheImpaler `Appl.ApplId` has a unique constraint and the primary key for this table is `Appl.ApplNbr`.

Comment: Oracle and PL/SQL are **not case sensitive**. Therefore `ApplID` and `applId` are exactly the same identifier. The PL/SQL scoping rules work from the inside out, which means that both sides of the `=` are treated as being the column name. Effectively your WHERE clause is `where 1=1`. It is good practice to use unique identifiers for parameter names: a common convention is to prefix them with `p_` such as `p_applid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an alias for the related table (`Appl`):

```
   PROCEDURE deleteAppl(applId IN VARCHAR2) IS
   .....
   .....
   SELECT ApplNbr 
    INTO lvnApplNbr
    FROM Appl a
    WHERE a.ApplID = applId;
   ......
```

or change your parameter's name (`applId`) to another name such as `i_applId` :

```
   PROCEDURE deleteAppl(i_applId IN VARCHAR2) IS
   .....
   .....
   SELECT ApplNbr 
    INTO lvnApplNbr
    FROM Appl
    WHERE ApplID = i_applId;
   ......
```

Because in your case multiple matching perceived, if your `parameter's name` and `column name` are identical.

Comment: Wow, I even confirmed it by running SQL inside the debugger session. It was confusing the parameter's name with the column name. I was essentially selecting **all** `ApplNbr` from the table `Appl`.

Comment: `deleteAppl.applId` would refer to the parameter name, if you really don’t want to prefix the name. Plain `applId`, in a query of a table with an `applId` column, is going to refer to the column.